# Best way to find minimum x and y values in a list of pairs in python?

Tags: python, performance, list

Given a list of data:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -1], [1, -1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2]]
```

What is the fastest way in python to get the lowest X and Y in a pair.
In this case [-1,-1].

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: using a for loop to cycle through each one and test it versus the previous lowest that it had found.

Comment: `best`? Can you be more specific? Do you want speed, clean pythonic code.. ?

Comment: so essentially you want to reduce your list of lists to a tuple of the lowest values?

Comment: Do both X and Y have to *both* be the lowest?  What if you had a pair that was [-50, 0]?   In which sense would that not be the lowest?

Comment: I don't want to find the lowest point, but rather return the pair of the lowest and and lowest Y. In this case best as in fastest.

Comment: @BenLongo I thought you were looking for a fast solution not small?

Comment: Any reason for unchecking my answer after like 10-11 months?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure it's the fastest, but it's probably the shortest and most 'pythonic':

```
>>> map(min, zip(*data))
[-1, -1]
```

---

*Update:* I did some timing analysis on this, too, using a list of 10000 random sublists and 100 iterations. Turns out it's a bit faster than *Aशwini*'s `itemgetter` solution, but the ordinary `for`-loop is still the fastest:

```
0.400840   min_mapminzip
0.579334   min_itemgetter
0.292459   min_loop
```

That was for Python 2.x... with Python 3, where `zip`, `map` etc. are iterators, it's another story:

```
0.186229   min_mapminzip   # wrong result, see below
0.686008   min_itemgetter
0.336031   min_loop
```

*Correction:* I forgot to apply `list` in the cases where `map` is an iterator, thus creating the iterator but not doing any real work... Thanks to *gnibbler* and *Aशwini* for pointing this out! With `list(map(...))`, the execution times are pretty much the same as in Python 2.x, i.e. the plain old loop is still the fastest.

---

*Update 2:* Interestingly, the "map-min-zip" solution is faster only for relatively short lists -- 'short' as in about 10,000 items. For longer lists, about 100,000 and more, the "itemgetter" solution becomes faster. And the plain for-loop is always the fastest...

Comment: I _am_ sure it's not the fastest (unfortunately). Especially on Python2 where `zip` creates a new list. Even `izip` is a lot slower than the for loop though.

Comment: @gnibbler I just did some analysis. Turns out, on Python 3 it _is_ fastest, at least when I tried. Feel free to double-check. UPDATE: Just tried with `imap` and `izip`: Interestingly, `izip` does not make much of a difference, but `imap` does! Any idea, why?

Comment: Are you sure you called `list()` on the iterator returned by `map` in Python 3? Because I am getting different results. (I tested on 90,000 items)

Comment: @tobias_k, `imap` (or `map` in Python3) doesn't do any real work until you iterate over the result. Using `list()` is one way to do that.

Comment: @Aशwini and gnibbler: You are right, I just ran the tests without looking at the actual result of the function. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `min` here:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -1], [1, -1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2]]
>>> x = min(lst, key=itemgetter(0))[0]
>>> y = min(lst, key=itemgetter(1))[1]
>>> x, y
(-1, -1)
```

Takes around 1 second for 9000000 items on my system(i5 4670):

```
In [3]: lst = lst*10**6

In [4]: %timeit (min(lst, key=itemgetter(0))[0], min(lst, key=itemgetter(1))[1])
1 loops, best of 3: 1.01 s per loop
```

A normal single loop version took around 341 ms:

```
def find_min(seq):
    min_x = float('inf')
    min_y = float('inf')
    for x, y in seq:
        if x < min_x : min_x = x
        if y < min_y : min_y = y
    return min_x, min_y
```

Timing comparison:

```
len(lst)
Out[42]: 9000000

%timeit find_min(lst)
1 loops, best of 3: 341 ms per loop

%timeit map(min, zip(*lst))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.21 s per loop

%timeit map(min, izip(*lst))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.14 s per loop

%timeit (min(lst, key=itemgetter(0))[0], min(lst, key=itemgetter(1))[1])
1 loops, best of 3: 1.04 s per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
minima = data[0]
for pair in data[1:]:
    minima = map(min, zip(pair, minima))
```